# "Cannot add foreign key constraint" error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting this error and I am not sure what I'm doing wrong. I

Error SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE members
(
  member_ID INT NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  phone CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  rating VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  hashed_password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  member_level INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (member_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (member_level) REFERENCES member_level(member_level)
)
```

MySQL said:

```
#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

The SQL I'm trying to run is below, I can't figure out what the problem with it is

```
CREATE TABLE category
(
  category_ID INT NOT NULL,
  category_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (category_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE member_level
(
  member_level CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  member_level_description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (member_level)
);
CREATE TABLE members
(
  member_ID INT NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  phone CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  rating VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  hashed_password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  member_level INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (member_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (member_level) REFERENCES member_level(member_level)
);
CREATE TABLE tools
(
  tool_ID INT NOT NULL,
  serial_number VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  tool_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  tool_description VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  tool_picture VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  Member_ID INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (tool_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (member_ID) REFERENCES members(member_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE tool_category
(
  tool_ID INT NOT NULL,
  category_ID INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (tool_ID) REFERENCES tools(tool_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (category_ID) REFERENCES category(category_ID)
);
-- Populate tables
INSERT INTO member_level VALUES ('a', 'admin');
INSERT INTO member_level VALUES ('m', 'member');
```

Comment: I might be reading this incorrectly but it looks like your `FOREIGN KEY (member_level) REFERENCES member_level(member_level)` in members is suggesting the `members.member_level ` will reference `member_level.member_level`.  that looks to me to be an INT referencing a CHAR(1).

Comment: It looks like the following question answers yours: [Cannot Add foreign key constraint in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37967132/cannot-add-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql). In both cases, the answer seems to be that the key types are different on either side of the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

`member_level` in table `members` is of type `int`, while in table `member_level` is of type `CHAR(1)`.

They must be the same type.